# Array values in triangular shape Python

Tags: python, arrays, list

I am trying to take values from a given array in a right angle triangular shape.
I have tried following code:

```
matrix =     [[1,2,3],
          [4,5,6],
          [7,8,9],
          [10,11,12]]

row = 3
col =3

new = []

for i in range(0, row):

    for j in range(0, col):

        if (i > j):

            print("", end=" ")

        else:
            new.append(new[i][j])

                 end=" ")
print(new)
```

However this makes the new list 'new' have the values 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 9. So the triangle is going to the right side of the array. I am looking to have this new list have the values 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7 instead. I know the issue is with the 2nd for loop but I have tried experimenting with the code and haven't been able to get it quite right.

Comment: This is not valid Python code, and `img` is never defined.

Comment: Sorry, img was supposed to be new. Also this is valid python code as I've been testing it in a python editor and it works fine!

Comment: You want to change `if i > j` to `if (col - i) <= j`.

Comment: Worked perfectly, thank you very much

Comment: As posted, it has syntax error(s).

Comment: Apparently not since its running fine

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following:

```
>>> [row[:i] for row, i in zip(matrix, range(3, 0, -1))]
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [7]]
```

This takes decreasing slices of the rows in the matrix by [`zipping`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) the matrix with a [`range`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) of appropriate stop indeces. And if you want a flat list, you can nest the comprehension:

```
>>> [x for row, i in zip(matrix, range(3, 0, -1)) for x in row[:i]]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7]
```